# 3d Window effect is Disabled in CompizConfig Setting Manager?

Tags: ccsm

[image]

How to enable it? I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION: open CCSM->Go to preferences ->plugin list-> enable automatic plugin.
Now you can enable any check box u want to.**